# How to make new image file in a directory?

Tags: c#

I have tried this type of code

```
if (!Directory.Exists(Application.StartupPath + @"\product"))
   Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.StartupPath + @"\product");
```

So when I input a name for a product, i.e: Great, then I browse the product image, i.e: Television.jpg, then the name of the file will change into the name I have inputted in name field, so it will go like Great.jpg in the browse field.

Therefore I can create the data but when I click the data there is no image, because there are no file with the name Great.jpg.

But my friend use this code and then the image appeared. This code will create a new file with the same file format, but differ name. So it will create Greate.jpg file.

What can I do to have the same result as my friend?

Comment: The call to `Directory.Exists` is redundant. Please read the docs.

Answer (score 1):

All your code you have provided does is create the directory, it doesn't move anything to it.

You didn't copy the part of your friends code that does the actually copying when you borrowed the answer.

Moving or copying the file requires more code.

Try Looking at:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc148994(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc148994%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)